# Efficient Way to Balance Array of Integers in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, random, transformation

The following code

```
import numpy as np
W   = 5         # any odd positive integer
L   = 7         # any positive integer
M   = (W-1)//2
arr = np.random.choice(range(W),L) - M
```

generates an array of length `L` with numbers ranging from `-M` to `M`. Now I want to amend this array such that its sum is 0 (while keeping the restriction that elements are within `-M` to `M`).

I want to achieve this by adding **increments of +1** (if the initial sum is negative) or **increments of -1** (if the initial sum is positive) to the elements of this array, starting from the **first element** of the list (and then the second, third, etc. should I need to). For example, if the initial sum is -2 (i.e. negative) and the array is `[2,0,-1,...]` then I cannot increment by the first element by +1 (it's already at max `W=2`), and thus I need to increment the second element two times, resulting in `[2,2,-1,...]`.

Three samples:

```
[-1,  0,  0, -1,  2,  0, 2] ---> [-2, -1,  0, -1,  2,  0, 2]
or
[-2, -2,  1, -2,  0, -1, 2] ---> [ 2, -2,  1, -2,  0, -1, 2]
or 
[ 2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2, 2] ---> [-2, -2, -2,  0,  2,  2, 2]
```

It's easy to write a few for/while loops which do this, but is there a more efficient way (perhaps a numpy function)?

Comment: I'm assuming the resultant list should also only contain numbers ranging from `-W` to `W`?

Comment: There are multiple ways to sum to zero.  Your last example could have also been `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`  You must do a better job explaining the "rules" for balancing.

Comment: Added more details.

Comment: In your examples there is always # of +-1 is even, same for +-2. Is [-1, -1, +2, +1, +1, -2, 0] a valid output?

Comment: This is an ugly, niche problem that isn't intuitive. I can't see an elegant solution here, and any clever solution will simply be difficult to debug in the future. What's wrong with solving using a loop?

Comment: And there is another problem: `generates an array of length L with numbers ranging from -W to W` is not right - it would generate numbers from [-M...M], not [-W...W]. Use `arr = np.random.choice(range(-M, M+1),L) ` instead.